# I am trying to figure the best way to split up this function into two separate functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out the best way to split up this function into two separate functions. One being Main() and the other being determineStatus(). I have to use Main() to call determineStatus. The code does exactly what I want it to do just not sure a effective way to split it up.

Not really sure a way to split it up without getting tons of errors.

```
message="How many current credit hours do you have?"

def determineStatus(message):
  while True:
    try:
       userInput = int(input(message))       
    except ValueError:
       print("Please use whole numbers only. Not text nor decimals.")
       continue
    else:
       return userInput 

hours = determineStatus(message)
F=30
J=60
S=90
Max=200

if hours <= Max:
      if hours < F:
        print("You are classified as a Freshman")
  if hours > F and hours < J:
        print("You are classified as a Sophmore")
      if hours >= J and hours < S:
        print("You are classified as a Junior")
      if hours >= S and hours < Max:
        print("You are classified as a Senior")
else:
    print("With",hours," hours you are either an Alumni, 2nd Degree seeking student or lying about your hours.")

determineStatus(message)
```

Comment: Just put all the outer statements in a `def main():` and then call `main()`

Comment: what do you mean? @Chris Martin

Answer (score 2):

A right data structure is a great code-cutting tool.

```
# python 3.x

CLASSIFIER = [
    # (min, max, status)
    (0, 30, 'Freshman'),
    (30, 60, 'Sophomore'),
    (60, 90, 'Junior'),
    (90, 200, 'Senior'),
]


def classify(hours):
    assert hours >= 0, 'WTF, negative hours'
    for (lower, upper, status) in CLASSIFIER:
        if lower <= hours < upper:
            return status
    return 'Alumni, 2nd Degree seeking student or lying about your hours'


def ask(message):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print('Try entering a non-negative whole number again.')


def main():
    hours = ask('How many hours? ')
    print('With %d hours, you are %s' % (hours, classify(hours)))

# Optional: auto-invoke main() if we're being executed as a script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: when trying to use this coding it gives me syntax errors for every print statement.?

Comment: When running the test it doesnt even give any outputs.

Comment: not really sure what needs to be done to allow this to function but it does not.

Comment: @CharlesGoodling This is for Python 2.7, you have Python 3.x, wrap each `print` statement between brackets: `print('hi my name is')`.

Comment: CLASSIFIER contains redudant information. `min` isn't needed

Comment: I tryed that approach and when running the above code it does not prompt the user for a input

Comment: also would I have to close each function for it to work? Sorry im not as knowledgable as you guys.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Yes! I did that to simplify the code as much as possible, at the cost of some redundancy in the data. Showing the idea is more important here than giving the most polished solution. I'm afraid the OP would have harder time understanding something like `zip(classifier, classifier[1:])`.

Comment: So you changed all what I had around to make a better structure that doesnt even run? All I want to do was split the one function into multiple. Im not trying to be a expert in python nor are yall explaining any of the reasoning for anything that you guys have done. Your's makes the most sense yet doesnt function.

Comment: @CharlesGoodling: Hmm, I did check it before posting! My idea was exactly to show how smaller, well-defined pieces read and function better. I did just try it with Python 3.5 on my machine, it worked fine. Copy again, try again. Don't forget to call `main()`, apparently. I'm adding the auto-invocation of it.

Comment: @9000: You don't need to add any more logic, you need to remove some! Just remove the 2nd element of the tuple and replace `if lower <= hours < upper:` with `if hours < upper:`. Done

Comment: nope when i run the test function nothing happens it does not ask me to input my current credits

Comment: it works when i add that last section yet i dont even understand the purpose in that section nor do I even know what it is doing.

Comment: also it fails the -1 number testing function.

Comment: @EricDuminil: Fair enough, since we get the lower bound, 0, for free due to sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way.

Create a module

```
F = 30
J = 60
S = 90
Max = 200


def determineStatus(message):
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = int(input(message))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please use whole numbers only. Not text nor decimals.")
            continue
        else:
            return userInput


def calculateStatus(hours):
    if hours <= Max:
        if hours < F:
            return "You are classified as a Freshman"
    if hours > F and hours < J:
        return "You are classified as a Sophmore"
    if hours >= J and hours < S:
        return "You are classified as a Junior"
    if hours >= S and hours < Max:
        return "You are classified as a Senior"
    else:
        return "With {0} hours you are either an Alumni, 2nd Degree seeking student or lying about your hours.".format(hours)
```

Now create a little script:

```
import temp

message = "How many current credit hours do you have?"

# You can repeat the lines below by using a while loop

hours = temp.determineStatus(message)

print temp.calculateStatus(hours)
```

Comment: not even sure what you changed. I just need help splitting this one function into two functions.

Comment: @CharlesGoodling I did, I created 2 independent functions in the module and I called them from the script.

Comment: Your code doesnt even run. If im supposed to do soem script I know nothing about how to do that or even why to do it for this problem

Comment: @CharlesGoodling Yes I mentioned the script. See the last part of my post. There is a module and a script, that is 2 Python files. It will definitely run as long they are in the same directory on your hard drive. If you want them to be one file you can create a `def main()` like 9000 did.

Answer (score 0):

For your multiple `if`s, you get a warning from the Department of Redundancy Department!

If hours is not smaller than `J`, there's no need in checking it's greater than or equal to `J`.

Also, if `hours = F`, you'll return that the student is lying.

Finally, you won't return anything for `hours = Max`.

Here's an optimized `determine_status` function :

```
statuses = [
    (30, 'Freshman'),
    (60, 'Sophomore'),
    (90, 'Junior'),
    (200, 'Senior')
]


def determine_status(hours):
    for max_hours, status in statuses:
        if hours < max_hours:
            return "You are classified as a %s" % status
    return "With %d hours you are either an Alumni, 2nd Degree seeking student or lying about your hours." % hours

print(determine_status(0))
# You are classified as a Freshman
print(determine_status(30))
# You are classified as a Sophomore
print(determine_status(55))
# You are classified as a Sophomore
print(determine_status(75))
# You are classified as a Junior
print(determine_status(100))
# You are classified as a Senior
print(determine_status(205))
# With 205 hours you are either an Alumni, 2nd Degree seeking student or
# lying about your hours.
```

Comment: Yea im only allows to do stuff within Chapter or previous chapters which makes it tricky because a lot of what I know we have not quite discussed yet. Which is why I am asking the experts for assistance. I have the concept of this problem down it was just figurin out a way to simplify it without going to far within the book.

Comment: @CharlesGoodling My comment still stands for the redundancy, J and max, though.

Comment: I agree that it is redunant but still doesnt really help my question.

Comment: @CharlesGoodling: Well, my answer is more than half of the accepted answer, so it should have helped a bit.